# Component Vuejs2 declare $data obj to share data between components

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to make a Vue2 component to all the select of my app so would be easier later to change it if necessary!

I've based my research on the example given by the docs and I am breaking my head to figure out why should I speficy all the object on the data attr to make it work!

The following code is working properly, but if we change:
`data: { record: { category_id: null } }` by `data: { record: {} }` it stop to work!

Must be said the $data.record is loaded by ajax... would I always specify the whole object even knowing that after the ajax request I am going to replace all with something like `this.record = response.data`?

If somebody need there is FIDDLE [ https://jsfiddle.net/gustavobissolli/4xrfy54e/1/ ]

EDIT: SORRY GUYS JUST FIXED FIDDLE LINK

```js
Vue.component('select2', {
  props: ['options', 'value'],
  template: '#select2-template',
  data() {
    return {
      model: ''
    }
  },
  mounted: function() {
    this.model = this.value
  },
  watch: {
    value: function(value) {
      this.model = value
    },
    model: function(value) {
      this.$emit('input', value)
    },
  }
})

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#el',
  template: '#demo-template',
  data: {
    record: {
      category_id: null
    },
    options: [{
      id: 1,
      text: 'Hello'
    }, {
      id: 2,
      text: 'World'
    }]
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="el"></div>

<!-- using string template here to work around HTML <option> placement restriction -->
<script type="text/x-template" id="demo-template">
  <div>
    <pre>{{ $data | json }}</pre>
    <select2 :options="options" v-model="record.category_id" value="record.category_id"></select2>
  </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-template" id="select2-template">
  <select v-model="model">
    <option disabled>Select...</option>
    <option v-for="opt in options" :value="opt.id">{{ opt.text }}</option>
  </select>
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you are trying to edit a value which didn't arrive yet? :-)

The thing is: at the moment `v-model="record.category_id"` is "executed", you have **nothing** there, ie, there is no "category_id" at the "record" object. So, it binds to nothing. This is why the `select` won't work if you omit the "category_id" at `data` initialization.

But your assumption that when data arrives from server (ajax call) the component will not work, is wrong.

I have updated your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4xrfy54e/4/

1. First, use the dropdown before clicking the button: since it is binded to nothing, it will not update anything. This is correct.
2. Now, click the button. The button is simulating that data arrived from the server, and is assigned to `this.record` of the vm.
3. Play with the dropdown again: since record.category_id exists now, the binding is working fine.

Please, read the "[Reactivity in Depth](https://vuejs.org/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats)" documentation page, and you will stop breaking your head :-)

Comment: @j-bruni thanks a lot! Now is pretty clear why my component is not working!